# Conditional Expectation with Indicator Functions for Poisson Process First Jump Time (Option Pricing PDE)

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

This is supposed to be for the derivation of a PDE for pricing a specific type of option, from the book 'Nonlinear Option Pricing' (Guyon).

The option delivers $g(\tau, X_{\tau})$ at time $\tau$ if $\tau < T$, or it delivers $g(T,X_T)$ at time $T$ if $\tau \geq T$. $\tau$ is the first time of jump for a Poisson process with intensity $\beta(t)$ (which is independent of information up to time $t$). So the current time is $t$ and the option maturity is $T$ (unless jump occurs earlier).

The $r(s,X_s)$ values below is just the rate used to discount the payoffs, so I'm not sure it's relevant for the question I have.

So the option price at time $t$ is $$\mathbb{E}{\large[}1_{\tau \geq T} * e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s)ds}g(T,X_T) + 1_{\tau < T} * e^{-\int_{t}^{\tau}r(s,X_s)ds}g(\tau, X_{\tau})  | X_t = x {\large]}$$

I understand up to that point. After that this equation is set equal to the following: $$\mathbb{E}{\large[}e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s) + \beta(s)ds}g(T,X_T) + \int_{t}^{T}\beta(s)g(s,X_s)e^{-\int_{t}^{s}r(u,X_u) + \beta(u)du}ds)  | X_t = x {\large]}$$

I have no idea how the second term in the sum comes about. The first term I can see comes from the following (I think): $$\mathbb{E}{\large[}1_{\tau \geq T} * e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s)ds}g(T,X_T)| X_t = x {\large]} = \\
\mathbb{E}{\large[}1_{\tau \geq T} | X_t = x {\large]} * \mathbb{E}{\large[}e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s)ds}g(T,X_T)| X_t = x {\large]} = \\ 
\mathbb{E}{\large[}1_{\tau \geq T} {\large]} * \mathbb{E}{\large[}e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s)ds}g(T,X_T)| X_t = x {\large]} = \\
e^{-\int_{t}^{T}\beta(s)ds} * \mathbb{E}{\large[}e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s)ds}g(T,X_T)| X_t = x {\large]} = \\
\mathbb{E}{\large[}e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s) + \beta(s)ds}g(T,X_T)  | X_t = x {\large]} $$

So basically I am wondering how to get from $$\mathbb{E}{\large[}1_{\tau < T} * e^{-\int_{t}^{\tau}r(s,X_s)ds}g(\tau, X_{\tau})  | X_t = x {\large]}$$ to $$\mathbb{E}{\large[}\int_{t}^{T}\beta(s)g(s,X_s)e^{-\int_{t}^{s}r(u,X_u) + \beta(u)du}ds | X_t = x {\large]}$$ assuming that I calculated the other part properly.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Please don’t cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3092410/conditional-expectation-with-indicator-functions-for-poisson-process-first-jump

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the book, it is assumed that $\tau$ is the first time of jump of the Poisson process $N_t$ with deterministic intensity $\beta(t) >0$, independent of the filtration $(\mathcal{F}_t)$. Then, for any $ u > t \ge 0$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\tau > u \mid \tau > t) &= e^{-\int_t^u \beta(s) ds}.
\end{align*}
That is, the density of $\tau$, conditional on $\tau > t$, is given by 
$\beta(u) e^{-\int_t^u \beta(s) ds}$, for $u > t$.

Let $\mathcal{F}_{\infty} = \cup_{t\ge 0} \mathcal{F}_t$. Then, for any Borel set $A$, based on the independence condition of $\tau$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\infty}$,
\begin{align*}
&\ \mathbb{E}\left(\left(\mathbb{I}_{\tau \geq T} \, e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s)ds}g(T,X_T) + \mathbb{I}_{\tau < T}\, e^{-\int_{t}^{\tau}r(s,X_s)ds}g(\tau, X_{\tau})\right) \mathbb{I}_{X_t \in A}\, \big|\, \tau > t \right)\\
=&\ \mathbb{E}\bigg(\bigg(e^{-\int_t^T \beta(s) ds} e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s)ds}g(T,X_T) \\
&\qquad\quad + \int_t^T e^{-\int_{t}^{u}r(s,X_s)ds}g(u, X_{u})\, \beta(u)\, e^{-\int_t^u \beta(s) ds} du\bigg) \mathbb{I}_{X_t \in A}\bigg)\\
=&\ \mathbb{E}\left(\left(e^{-\int_t^T r(s,X_s) + \beta(s) ds} g(T,X_T) + \int_t^T e^{-\int_{t}^{u}\beta(s) + r(s,X_s)ds}g(u, X_{u})\, \beta(u)\, du\right) \mathbb{I}_{X_t \in A}\right).
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
&\ \mathbb{E}\left( 1_{\tau \geq T} * e^{-\int_{t}^{T}r(s,X_s)ds}g(T,X_T) + 1_{\tau < T} e^{-\int_{t}^{\tau}r(s,X_s)ds}g(\tau, X_{\tau})\, \big|\, \tau > t, X_t = x \right)\\
=&\ \mathbb{E}\left(e^{-\int_t^T r(s,X_s) + \beta(s) ds} g(T,X_T) + \int_t^T \beta(u)\, e^{-\int_{t}^{u}\beta(s) + r(s,X_s)ds}g(u, X_{u})\, du \, \big|\, X_t = x \right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Where does the indicator function for $X_t \in A$ come from? It looks like it's related to the condition $X_t = x$ but I've never seen something done like that before. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. That is the formal definition for the expectation conditional on $X_t=x$.

Comment: See Definition 4 on Page 220 of [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Probability-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics-v/dp/0387945490) by Shiryaev.

Comment: How did you expand this term: $\mathbb{I}_{\tau < T}\, e^{-\int_{t}^{\tau}r(s,X_s)ds}g(\tau, X_{\tau})$ to $ \int_t^T e^{-\int_{t}^{u}r(s,X_s)ds}g(u, X_{u})\, \beta(u)\, e^{-\int_t^u \beta(s) ds} du$ Did you use the same technique of the indicator functions that the previous answer did or something else?

Comment: It is the expectation by treating it as a function of $\tau$, while others are held fixed. That is, something like $E(F(\tau))$.

Comment: How come we can treat $g(\tau,X_\tau)$ as a function of $\tau$? (Basically how come $X_\tau$ is able to be held fixed?) Did you implicitly do a step of conditioning on the entire path of $(X_s)_{t \leq s \leq T}$. That would make the function $g$, conditional on the entire path of $X$, a function of $\tau$ only. Or did you follow some other rationale? (Sorry for so many questions, I'm trying to understand the steps/logic someone more experienced would take)

Comment: Note that $X_t=X(\omega, t)$, where $\omega$ is a random sample, That is, $X_{\tau} = X(\omega, \tau)$, where $\omega$ is independent of $\tau$. Then you can use the independence as in Lemma 2.3.4 of [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Stochastic-Calculus-Finance-II-Continuous-Time/dp/144192311X) by Shreve.

Answer (score 3):

The density of the random variable $\tau$ is like you pointed out;

$$\phi(s):=E[\delta(\tau-s)|\tau \geq t] = e^{-\int_t^s\beta(u)du}\beta(s)$$

where we called $\delta$ the *Dirac* density function ($P(X=x):=E[\delta(X-x)]$ for any random variable eg)

So you just need to plug this explicitly in the expectation to get the result (exactly same way as what you did to show that $E[1_{\tau>T}]=e^{-\int_t^T\beta(u)du}$ )

In general you can write for any function $h$

$$h(\tau,X_\tau) = \int ds \delta(\tau -s)h(s,X_s)$$

so taking expectation one has (taking into account the independence property of $\tau$ from previous information:

$$E[h(\tau,X_\tau)|X_t=x] = \int ds E[\delta(\tau -s)h(s,X_s)|X_t=x]$$
$$E[h(\tau,X_\tau)|X_t=x] = \int ds E[\delta(\tau -s)]E[h(s,X_s)|X_t=x]  = \int ds \phi(s)E[h(s,X_s)|X_t=x]$$

Comment: I still can't see how the function $g(\tau, X_{\tau})$ becomes a part of the integral. Would you mind showing some of the steps? Thanks

Comment: How come $\delta(\tau - s)$ is conditionally independent of $h(s,X_s)$? Isn't information about the value of $\tau$ affecting the value of $h(s,X_s)$. In the part that I was able to do before, $g(T,X_T)$ was set regardless of the value taken on by $\tau$, but this doesn't seem to be the case with $\delta(\tau - s)h(s,X_s)$

Comment: Pleasd specify clearly the assumptions made on $\tau$ as done in your book then. From your question it seemed you assumed $X$ and $\tau$ are independent.

Comment: $X$ and $\tau$ are independent but isn't a function of $\tau$ ($h(\tau, X_\tau)$) not independent of $\tau$?

Comment: @Slade i showed in my answer how to extract the dependency in $\tau$ by using the dirac function. I believe my argument is complete with the assumption of independence.